# Переименовать файл

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. У меня скопилось огромное количество фотографий и мне хотелось бы привести их к общему виду, то есть переименовать в формат типа IMG_0001 и так далее. Подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь способ реализовать это на с++?

Comment: [`std::rename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename)?

Comment: А как это реализовать для кучи фоток с рандомными именами?

Comment: Читать оглавление и переименовывать, наращивая счетчик.

Посмотрите `man opendir` и SEE ALSO к нему.

Answer (score 3):

воспользуйтесь boost::filesystem, удобно и в интернете примеров куча, настолько, что даже писать ответ не хочется. Копипастну содержимое первого попавшегося примера из google.

```
  if ( exists( dir_path ) )
  {
      directory_iterator end_itr; // default construction yields past-the-end
      for ( directory_iterator itr( dir_path );
            itr != end_itr;
            ++itr )
      {
          if ( is_file(itr->status()) )
          {
           //DO YOUR STUFF   
          }
      }
  }
```

Примерно такой код у Вас получится. Удобно и понятно. Сможете извлечь при помощи [этой хелпы](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) все, что нужно. А главное, получившийся код будет кроссплатформенным.